# given tx hash: tokens transfered?

Tags: blockchain, tokens

I have a transaction hash (for example 0xd97a7f7e15709ce345842a52a6e8db395e6ba779fd76a426b1878512a34a8128) I would need the information in red, basically the tokens involved (the first one is an ERC20 token, while the latter is an ERC721).

[image: tokens information]

can you point me in the right direction to get this information via API? I would like to use a Python script but I can give also a try to JS.

I tried with [blockcypher API](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/0xd97a7f7e15709ce345842a52a6e8db395e6ba779fd76a426b1878512a34a8128) but it seems they only give me basic information (nothing I can recognize on tokens)

I don't own a full node, maybe I can use infura.io with a free account?

I think to fetch directly the
[etherscan web page](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd97a7f7e15709ce345842a52a6e8db395e6ba779fd76a426b1878512a34a8128) but it seems a bit dirty...

thank you

Answer (score 1):

ERC20 / ERC21 contracts emit a `Transfer` event when a token is transferred. That is how Etherscan is able to identify all the token transfers that took place and display them to you.

You can do this yourself by looking at the logs in the transaction receipt. Infura would work fine, along with your web3 framework of choice (probably the web3py package if you want to work in Python)